# WSL Ubuntu cycles through Agend pid #'s endlessly until I press cntrl c on startup or login

Tags: command-line, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've got an ubuntu installation that is running some software for my company, and I've added some paths to the .bashrc file. When I start WSL with `wsl -b ubuntu`, it prints out this, and keeps going until I hit control-c.

```
Agent pid 549
Agent pid 556
Agent pid 563
Agent pid 570
Agent pid 577
Agent pid 584
```

This is the line I've added

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin && source $HOME/.profile
```

Do I need to add something else, or a kill statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `&& source $HOME/.profile` from the add'ed line.

As it is now, it reloads your .profile which apparently starts Agent program before ,profile is reloaded (soure'd) again.

Answer (score 0):

If your `~/.profile` is based on the default Ubuntu one (copied from the `/etc/skel` directory on account creation), then you'll notice that it contains the following lines:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

in other words, `~/.profile` sources `~/.bashrc` when it detects that you are running a bash shell. The intention is to make login shells behave as similarly as possible to interactive non-login shells.

Hence if you *also* source `~/.profile` from `~/.bashrc`, you end up in an infinite loop in which one file repeatedly sources the other.